# BPMN - system lane/pool?

Tags: system, pool, bpmn

I am modeling some processes to be used by non-IT people (i.e. they need to be as clear as possible but I also don't wanna break any BPMN rules).

I attached a mockup of what I'm trying to show => a person performs some steps in the system but it's also important for the people reading the model to understand what system does after each of the user steps (e.g. that system automatically calculates a risk score). What's the best practice to model this in BPMN? I assume in any case (read: if this is a good approach in general) it is a pool, not a lane - but in this case the system pool would also need a start and finish, right?

[image: BPMN mockup:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is part of your organization so model it as a separate lane in the same pool as the rest of your process.
To indicate if the step is automated or done by a user use action types - script for steps done automatically by the system and user for those performed by a user.
Actions within the same pool are connected with solid lines to indicate business flow.

Answer (score 1):

If we use MDA/CIM system not modeled as a part of proces (lane). Software is the tool not role....

(PS two pools, one for company second for system is bad, BPMN use one poll for one proces...).

We use mapping "activity to use case" for showing where is the system using.